# How to set PublicKeyToken of assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to set specific PublicKeyToken to assembly. In properties of project I can set version and package Id but I couldn't find the way to set PublicKeyToken :

[image: Project properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the public key token, you need to add a strong-name to the assembly, on the Signing tab:

[image]

It is *this* that defines the public key. If you need to use a *specific* public key, then you'll need the keys that go with that, or you'll have to delay-sign it on a build server (which takes longer to explain).

Comment: It is not working or I didn't understand. I choose New enter my public key. It is generating snk file. I publish my package, but PublicKeyToken is different. Can you show all steps please?

Comment: @DilshodK packages and assemblies are different things; where and how are you looking to see the public key token that is "different"? The "all steps" for signing assemblies (at least, via the UI route): is as above.

Comment: I am setting 5bb2a467cbec794e to publik key. When I rebuild and see assembly from dot Peek it is showing dccbd7ce7d6a58c0

Comment: @DilshodK well, by default: assemblies *aren't strong named*, so: there's something in your build that is doing this. Look in your csproj or build mechanism.

Comment: It is what I want to ask

Comment: @DilshodK I *can't see your csproj or your build script*, so: it is really hard for me to comment on that; in new-style (SDK) csproj, you're looking for `AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile`; if you're using `csc`, you're looking for `-keyfile`. But once again: **I can't see your build**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232336/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-marc-gravell).